# Building my first Android app from a website I created locally and am having issues with CORS

Tags: javascript, android, html, json, cors

I built a website that I use locally for personal use only, and I am trying to convert it to an Android app. I have several buttons that when clicked, call a JS function, passing a variable (the name of the json) to the function. In order for this to work locally, I needed to set up a server, which I did successfully using XAMPP. The site works perfectly locally.

I am using Android Studio to wrap my files (in the assets folder). I'm using a webView in my MainActivity. I can start the app and see the page load, however, my files are being blocked by the CORS policy. I have tried a few different "fixes" to attempt to get around this, but have had no luck.

Originally my JS was using a fetch to get the json data. Apparently I don't need to do anything when using a WebView. This turned out to be false. The first fix I tried to implement was XMLHttpRequest. This failed. The second thing I tried was using AssetManager, also with no luck.

The functionality:
The page loads, and on loading, calls the loadQuestions function, which passes a variable to show the initial question content, based on a json. I can then click a button from the side menu which will pass a different json variable to the loadQuestions function, which loads the new questions.
eg. loadQuestions(questions1.json)

`<button onclick="loadQuestions('questions2.json');">Questions 2</button>`

Inside the loadQuestions function is a snippet of code to handle the json data

```
fetch(fileToLoad)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      questions = data;

    // Doing things with my json data

    })
      .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error loading questions:', error);
    });
```

I'm sure there's an easy solution to this, but I just can't have any luck with it.

Please let me know if you need anything else to help debug / solve my small but annoying problem. TYIA

**** UPDATE ****

I managed to get the XMLHttpRequest code to work. It was a challenge, but hours of searching came up with a solution.

In my MainActivity file, I added the following line of code. I know there is a security risk, however, I will be the only one using the app.

webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

Comment: `I have tried a few different "fixes"` were any of these fixes targeting the **server**, since the server is what controls CORS

Comment: @JaromandaX well that's just the thing, it's not supposed to trigger a server response (CORS) by using the solutions I tried. That's what's confusing.

Comment: is it not a cross origin request? can you show the error?

Comment: @JaromandaX
I have since removed the code, however, this is the current error:
script.js:220 Fetch API cannot load file:///android_asset/questions.json. URL scheme "file" is not supported.

Comment: `URL scheme "file"` ahh yes, XMLHttpRequest/fetch don't do `file://` protocol - so, you won't be able to use XMLHttpRequest/fetch at all